# Como verificar se um ResultSet está vazio?

Tags: java, mysql, java-8

Estou fazendo uma consulta no MySQL e quando a consulta existe ele retorna os valores de boa.

Mas eis a pergunta, o qual valor o `ResultSet` recebe quando a busca não existe? Tipo procuro por um nome nos registros da tabela se esse nome não existe no banco o que é retornado?

Já procurei na internet mas não encontro nada relacionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o método [`ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst--) retorna falso:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection( ... );
stmt = con.prepareStatement( ... );

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    // Não há dados, faça algo aqui...
}
```

O `isBeforeFirst` vai retornar `false` se o *cursor* não estiver antes do primeiro registro ou se não tiver linhas no [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), ou `true` caso contrário.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! funcionou perfeitamente! Queria saber onde posso pesquisar mais sobre o assunto. existe algum livro específico detalhando o JDBC?

Comment: @ChristianoOliveira Disponha. Na documentação tem um tutorial sobre, veja: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/